# Analyzing parking occupancy patterns

Tags: sequential-pattern-mining

I'm working with a data set of parking lot occupancy changes over time

[Park Stat] int value indicates the park state and varies as follow:

1. Fully Occupied
2. Few free slots
3. Available

The data is stored as a slowly changing fact table with time ranges, using start and end date-time fields, data sample:

[image]

Looking at the parking stat behavior, it hard to see a clear pattern when the parking is usually free, you can see below the changes in the same park over weeks:
[image]

In general, there are weekdays seasonality working days (Sunday - Wednesday) and weekends (Thursday, Friday - Saturday)

Two main challenges:

1. How to remove white noise without damaging the ability to recognize repetitive patterns
2. How to find repetitive patterns in the parking occupancy in order to identify the parking free time slots with high confidence (90%)

Thanks for the help

Amir